# How to use datepicker in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to add datepicker in my code. I downloaded bootstrap-datepicke. But how add correct this component? I tried something like this

```
<form action="{{ path('pattient_test') }}" method="post" >
   <input type="text" id="pick" value="02/16/12" data-date-format="mm/dd/yy" class="datepicker" >
   <input type="submit" value="Prześlij zmienione dane"/>
</form>
```

And then in controller

```
 var_dump( $this->get('request')->request->get('pick'));
```

But I still get NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by adding `name` attribute to your pick input field,

```
name="pick"
```

**Also,**

`var_dump( $this->get('request')->request->all());` Allows you to check all POST parameters, it may help you figure out what's going wrong.